# Perl on XAMPP Server gives erorr 500

Tags: apache, perl, xampp

i am pretty new to perl, and i was trying to set up a web server which runs perl...

i did make it work with another script, but with this one i got this error:

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request.
>
> Error message:  End of script output before headers: index.pl
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11

This is my script:

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
use strict;
use warnings;

#Open file and define $pcontent as content of body.txt
open(FILE,"body.txt"); 
local $/;
my $pcontent = <FILE>;
close(FILE)

#Open file and define $ptitle as content of title.txt
open(FILE,"title.txt"); 
local $/;
my $ptitle = <FILE>;
close(FILE)

#open html code
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; 
print "<html>";

#set html page title
print "<head>";
print "<title>$ptitle</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";

#set the <body> of the html page
if ($pcontent = ""){
 print "
 <H1>ERROR OCCURED!</h1>"
} else{
print $pcontent;
};

#close the html code
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it isn't working is because your Perl code has syntax errors which prevent it from compiling. You can check your code for syntax errors by running

```
perl -c yourscript.pl
```

And if we do that we find:

```
syntax error at yourscript.pl line 11, near ")
```

If we look at line 11, we see that the line before is missing a semicolon at the end of the statement.

```
close(FILE)     # <--- need semicolon here.
```

But there are a few other problems with this script:

- You should avoid the use of global filehandles (`FILE`) and instead use lexical filehandles. One advantage is that since they are automatically destroyed at the end of their scope (assuming no references) they will be automatically `close`d for you.
- You should use the three-argument form of `open` which will help you catch certain bugs
- You should check that your `open` succeeds and report an error if it doesn't
- You should only `local`ize `$/` within a small block, otherwise it will affect other things in your program that you may not want it to
- If this script grows to be anything other than a trivial example, you should use a templating system rather than `print`ing a bunch of HTML.
- Your conditional is wrong; you need to use the `eq` operator for string equality, or `==` for numerical equality. The `=` operator is for assignment.

Putting that all together, here is how I would write it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#Open file and define $pcontent as content of body.txt
my $pcontent = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'body.txt' or die "Can not open body.txt: $!";
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

#Open file and define $ptitle as content of title.txt
my $ptitle = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'title.txt' or die "Can not open title.txt: $!";
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

#open html code
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; 
print "<html>";

#set html page title
print "<head>";
print "<title>$ptitle</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";

#set the <body> of the html page
if ($pcontent eq ""){
    print "<H1>ERROR OCCURED!</h1>"
} else{
    print $pcontent;
};

#close the html code
print "</body>";
print "</html>";
```

Comment: All good advice of course.  However, what do you think of recommending [`autodie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) instead of suggesting that a beginner include manual `or die` statements?  It seems to me that laziness pervades, and so not only does autodie handle the error messages automatically, it also includes a lot more information than the inevitable `or die $!` that we see so often.

Comment: `autodie` is also a great choice. I like to make sure people understand what's going on before giving them the shortcut, though. :)